# Why do I get duplicate output when using a for loop over a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

Hello I have problem looping when printing data in a list.

```
def inputScore(scor) :
    for i in range(len(scor)) :
        scor[i] = int(input("Enter Score Number : "))

def Display(scr) :
    for i in scr:
        if i >= 86 and i <= 100 :
            x = "A"
        elif i >= 70 and i < 86 :
            x = "B"
        elif i >= 60 and i < 70 :
            x = "C"
        elif i >= 50 and i < 60 :
            x = "D"
        elif i >= 0 and i < 50 :
            x = "E"
        else :
            print("Invalid Score")
        for i in range(0,3) : # If I remove this code "for..", it will error "IndexError: list index out of range"
            print("Score Number",scr[i],"Letter Grades", x)

def main () :
    scor = [int]*3
    inputScore(scor)
    Display(scor)
main()
```

Example:

```
# Input :
85
60
40

# Output that I want :
Score Number 85 Letter Grades A
Score Number 60 Letter Grades C
Score Number 40 Letter Grades E

# Output that I got :
Score Number 85 Letter Grades A
Score Number 60 Letter Grades A
Score Number 40 Letter Grades A

Score Number 85 Letter Grades C
Score Number 60 Letter Grades C
Score Number 40 Letter Grades C

Score Number 85 Letter Grades E
Score Number 60 Letter Grades E
Score Number 40 Letter Grades E
```

There are 3 looping for Letter Grades (A = 3 times, C = 3 times and E = 3 times), I tried to give `for i in range(0,3)` for stop looping but it doesn't work, Letter Grades always prints 9 times with 3 A, 3 C, and 3 E. How to solve it and make it output like in the example above?

Comment: It’s good time to try debug this program yourself to learn the logic - pythontutor.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `for` loop is unnecessary. The outer `for` loop already iterates through the scores. In each iteration, `i` is a *score*, not an *index* -- to get an index, you use `range`. Therefore, there's no need to index the `scr` list at all -- you would print `i` itself rather than `scr[i]`.

Also, with the current code, the grade for 85 would be `B` rather than `A`. Perhaps you need to adjust the bounds for the `A` and `B` grades.

Another issue is that for an invalid score, it would still attempt the final `print`. This would fail if an invalid score occurred as the first score (since `x` wouldn't be defined). If an invalid score occurred as a subsequent score, the `print` would show you the grade for the previous score, which you don't want. You can get around this by setting `x` to be the empty string at the start of each iteration and checking if it has a non-empty value before doing the final print of the grade.

The following code resolves the issues discussed:

```
def inputScore(scor):
    for i in range(len(scor)):
        scor[i] = int(input("Enter Score Number: "))

def display(scr):
    for i in scr:
        x = ""
        if i >= 85 and i <= 100:
            x = "A"
        elif i >= 70 and i < 85:
            x = "B"
        elif i >= 60 and i < 70:
            x = "C"
        elif i >= 50 and i < 60:
            x = "D"
        elif i >= 0 and i < 50:
            x = "E"
        else:
            print("Invalid Score")
        if x:
            print("Score Number:", i, "Letter Grade:", x)

def main():
    scor = [int] * 3
    inputScore(scor)
    display(scor)

main()
```